# String-based flags in python

Tags: python, string, flags

For my python-based class I'd like to limit the input strings to certain strings, as they represent the file endings I want to allow to be loaded, i.e.

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self, allowed_endings: Literal[".csv", ".txt", ".docx"] = ".docx") -> None:
        self.allowed_endings: Literal[".csv", ".txt", ".docx"] = allowed_endings
```

Now, I'd like to replace that implementation with a flag-based system, i.e.

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self, allowed_endings: AllowedFileEndings = AllowedFileEndings.TXT) -> None:
        self.allowed_endings: AllowedFileEndings = allowed_endings
```

such that I can write a similar class as

```
class DemoClass:
    def __init__(self, allowed_endings: AllowedFileEndings = AllowedFileEndings.TXT | AllowedFileEndings.CSV) -> None:
        self.allowed_endings: AllowedFileEndings = allowed_endings
```

I am aware of StrEnum, where I can create a class which behaves like enums, but also can be used to be compared with strings. Unfortunately, it does not work with with bitwise OR/AND-operators, as demonstrated above. Moreover, it only works for python 3.11 and above, while I'm limited to 3.9.

Is there a way to implement such a StrFlag-class in Python 3.9?

Ideally, I can then still use string-based comprehensions, i.e.

```
".csv" is in AllowedFileEndings.TXT | AllowedFileEndings.CSV
```

if possible.

Comment: Just for clarity, `|` is bitwise OR, not logical. Logical OR in Python is just `or`.

Comment: @matszwecja: Thanks for the correction, I implemented it

Comment: Did you consider using a `set` of the allowed strings?

Comment: Does the [Flag](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.Flag) class meet your needs? If not, what exactly do you need to work differently or additionally, and why? As an aside: `is in` is **not valid Python syntax** (you just mean `in`), and that code **is not** a "comprehension" of any kind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement custom behavior for `|` using `__or__` and `__ror__` methods of a class. By implementing them on top of StrEnum you should get a class that fits your needs.

Since `set` already behave like that (`|` on sets is their union), they are perfect data structure for our usecase.

```
from enum import StrEnum

class Extensions(StrEnum):
    TXT = ".txt"
    CSV = ".csv"
    DOCX = ".docx"
    DOC = ".doc"

    def __or__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, set):
            return {self} | other
        elif isinstance(other, Extensions):
            return {self, other}
        else:
            raise TypeError
    def __ror__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, set):
            return other | {self}
        elif isinstance(other, Extensions):
            return {other, self}
        else:
            raise TypeError
        
print(Extensions.TXT | Extensions.CSV | Extensions.DOCX)
```

You have to remember though that while `Extensions.TXT` can be treated as a string, `Extensions.TXT | Extensions.CSV` becomes a set and must be treated accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The described functionality is exactly what the `Flag` class is for:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class AllowedFileEndings(Flag):
    TXT = auto()
    CSV = auto()
    DOCX = auto()
```

It supports the expected bitwise/set boolean operators and set containment:

```
>>> txt_or_docx = AllowedFileEndings.TXT | AllowedFileEndings.DOCX
>>> txt_or_docx
<AllowedFileEndings.DOCX|TXT: 5>
>>> AllowedFileEndings.TXT in txt_or_docx
True
>>> AllowedFileEndings(7)
<AllowedFileEndings.DOCX|CSV|TXT: 7>
>>> txt_or_docx in AllowedFileEndings(7)
True
```

This can trivially be extended by adding a factory to construct from string, and perhaps overriding `__contains__` to coerce strings:

```
from enum import Flag, auto

class AllowedFileEndings(Flag):
    TXT = auto()
    CSV = auto()
    DOCX = auto()

    @classmethod
    def from_string(cls, s):
        if not s.startswith('.'):
            raise ValueError('extension must start with a dot')
        return cls[s[1:].upper()]

    def __contains__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, str):
            other = self.from_string(other)
        return super().__contains__(other)
```

which allows

```
>>> '.txt' in AllowedFileEndings(5)
True
```

Further extensions are left as an exercise (for example: have `from_string` accept a string containing `|`, and parse it to determine the desired value; override `__str__` and/or `__repr__`).